# Whats a good way to make XML with grails

Tags: xml, grails, groovy

Brief googling looks like you're supposed to use "MarkupBuilder," but I don't understand it.  It looks like I can do "as XML" having done `import grails.converters.XML` but this is not really giving me what I want.

I want this:

```
<Thingie>
  <someValue>blah</someValue>
  <hellaItems>
    <Item>
      <anotherValue>yaddayadda</anotherValue>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <anotherValue>different from the first</anotherValue>
    </Item>
  </hellaItems>

</Thingie>
```

I don't even know where to start...

@Stefan what if I want to do it dynamically?  I don't think I understand "builders" in general may be the issue.

```
def items = ["yaddayadda","different from the first"]
```

Update:  looks like im getting close, but can someone help me with this last part.  I am doing this:

```
def items = ["yaddayadda","different from the first"]
def writer = new StringWriter()
def xml = new MarkupBuilder(writer)
xml.thingie() {
  someValue('blah')
  hellaItems(){
      items.each{
          item(){
              anotherValue(it)
           }
      }


  }
}
def xmlString = writer.toString()
println "maybe this will just work"
println xmlString
```

prints:

```
maybe this will just work
<thingie>
  <someValue>blah</someValue>
  <hellaItems>
    <item>
      <anotherValue />
    </item>
    <item>
      <anotherValue />
    </item>
  </hellaItems>
</thingie>
```

Why aren't my `anotherValue`'s there?

UPDATE:  SOLVED using "tmpHolder" below, however Bill has a better syntax suggestion.

```
def items = ["yaddayadda","different from the first"]
def writer = new StringWriter()
def xml = new MarkupBuilder(writer)
xml.thingie() {
  someValue('blah')
  hellaItems(){
      items.each{
          def tmpHolder = it
          item(){
              anotherValue(tmpHolder)
           }
      }


  }
}
def xmlString = writer.toString()
println "maybe this will just work"
println xmlString
```

Comment: You're close, but I wouldn't use "it", especially if you have another closure inside.  try items.each { txt -> item() { anotherValue(txt)} }?

Comment: yes thats a lot better than tmpHolder.  I'm still learning to Groove.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder

def writer = new StringWriter()
def xml = new MarkupBuilder(writer)
xml.thingie() {
  someValue('blah')
  hellaItems(){
     item(){
        anotherValue('yaddayadda')
     }
     item(){
        anotherValue('different from the first')
     }
  }
}
```

`writer.toString()`

What don't you get? The syntax is a little weird, but that's because it's a DSL. It's not supposed to look like normal groovy "code". `as XML` works quite differently, and unless your object graph matches the XML you posted exactly, you won't get the results you want.

Comment: I don't think I can understand this answer until it has items.each{} somewhere.

Comment: Apparently I'm smarter than I thought.

Comment: You shouldn't need the method call () parens at the end of those elements.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, if you need fine-grained control over the XML that is generated, use `MarkupBuilder`. If you want to serialize to XML an object (graph) in the default manner, i.e. all properties are included in the markup, then feel free to use `someObject as XML`