# XML marshalling of nested elements in Grails using Groovy markup builder syntax

Tags: xml, grails, groovy, marshalling, markupbuilder

Grails: v2.5.0

How can I generate XML including nested elements without attributes?

This is my desired output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<list>
  <book>
    <title>Title</title>
    <authors>
      <author>
        <fname>First Name</fname>
        <lname>Last Name</lname>
      </author>
    </authors>
  </book>
</list>
```

Using the following marshaller...

```
// imports...

class BootStrap {

  def init = { servletContext ->
    XML.registerObjectMarshaller(Book) { Book book, converter ->
      converter.build {
        title book.title
        authors {
          for (a in book.authors) {
            author {
              fname a.fname
              lname a.lname
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

...the `authors` element is not included in the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<list>
  <book>
    <title>Title</title>
  </book>
</list>
```

However, when adding an attribute to both the `authors` and `author` elements...

```
// imports...

class BootStrap {

  def init = { servletContext ->
    XML.registerObjectMarshaller(Book) { Book book, converter ->
      converter.build {
        title book.title
        authors(bla: 'bla') {
          for (a in book.authors) {
            author(bla: 'bla') {
              fname a.fname
              lname a.lname
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

...the elements are included in the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<list>
  <book>
    <title>Title</title>
    <authors bla="bla">
      <author bla="bla">
        <fname>First Name</fname>
        <lname>Last Name</lname>
      </author>
    </authors>
  </book>
</list>
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution: add parentheses and an empty list.

Here's the code:

```
// imports...

class BootStrap {

  def init = { servletContext ->
    XML.registerObjectMarshaller(Book) { Book book, converter ->
      converter.build {
        title book.title
        authors([]) {
          for (a in book.authors) {
            author([]) {
              fname a.fname
              lname a.lname
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add empty brackets to the authors and author calls like this:

```
    converter.build {
      title book.title
      authors() {
        for (a in book.authors) {
          author() {
            fname a.fname
            lname a.lname
        }
      }
    }
```

See [this SO question with an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6686144/whats-a-good-way-to-make-xml-with-grails).